# How to call another classes super class?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Lets say I have three classes, A,B,C. B inherits A, is there a way to access the getVal method of Class A, in C?

```
    class A {

    getVal method
    }
    class B extends A {

    }
    Class C {
    main() {
    B x = new B
    x.getVal?
    }
```

Comment: In theory what you're trying should work, but it's impossible to say without seeing the actual code what the problem you're having might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Assuming the classes remain in the same package - x.getVal will work.

```
class A {
  String getVal(){
    return "from a";
  }
}
class B extends A {

}
public class C {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    B x = new B();
    x.getVal();
  }
}
```

It works - because of the default access modifier. Use the `protected` access modifier for inheritance.